# what is token? why do we need it?

Tags: tokens

I am just started to learn ethereum blockchain technology I came across the term token. I do not find the answer for what exactly token mean? and what its functionality and what situation we need it? Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 2):

The word token is used for an asset which utilizes an existing blockchain - it does not require its own blockchain. A token in the Ethereum ecosystem is a token which uses the Ethereum blockchain. On the other hand, cryptocurrency coins are typically something which requires its own blockchain - for example Ether is the cryptocurrency used in the Ethereum blockchain. There can typically be any number of different tokens on a blockchain but only one cryptocurrency.

In the Ethereum ecosystem tokens are created with smart contracts. There is no definite answer as to which contracts can be considered as tokens - basically anything which can be used to transfer value. There is also no authority on the issue so something one party considers a token may not be a token for another party.

**Token standards**

Often when someone mentions "Ethereum tokens" they are actually referring to ERC-20 standard compatible tokens. ERC-20 is (currently) the most common standard which defines how a token contract should be written.

Token standards are important for the ecosystem. If you create a random smart contract which you consider a token it still doesn't mean that anyone else knows how to use it. Anyone who wants to use the tokens needs to figure out how it works and write their own implementation for its usage. If the token contract is ERC-20 compatible everyone already knows how it should be used and a generic implementation is enough - that way the same implementation can be used for all ERC-20 compatible tokens.

For more information about ERC-20 have a look at https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/ERC20_Token_Standard

Answer (score 1):

Why do we need US dollars and many other currencies?

Also why do they keep printing USD $$$ out of nothing, while adding NO VALUE to it ?

In contract, you can make your tokens and add as much value to it as you want.

Answer (score 1):

In it’s simplest terms, it's just a unit of value.

It's mostly of two types : Utility and Security

- As a medium of Exchange
- As a Ownership or Stake in the platform

Answer (score 1):

The token is something that represents value. It could be representing a character in a game or representing lottery, tickets, or financial assets.

`tokens` in the blockchain are similar to tokens in casinos. You can buy tokens after entering the casino and then continue to play on different tables using the same tokens. these tokens are the currency for the casino, and the tables do not accept any other currency. Each Decentralized
Application Organization (DAO) has its own token just like a casino

token in blockchain exists digitally on a blockchain and is operated cryptographically, which means that they are generated, protected,
and transferred using cryptographic protocols.